# How do I replace a broken thermostat on a metal radiator?

Tags: heating

The thermostat swivels round and has no effect on the temperature.  The radiator is always very hot. How can I replace the thermostat?

Comment: Could you post a picture of the thermostat? You'll probably get better advice that way.

Answer (score 1):

Thermostats usually unscrew by hand with a small plastic thumbwheel at their base. Yours may be broken or have come unscrewed.  Replacement thermostats are quite cheap, about £10 - £20 GBP and should screw directly onto the metal valve.